# Rails routing error despite having route defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I have a route defined like this for my "evisit" controller and "all_messages" action

```
match "evisits/:token/all_messages" => "evisits#all_messages", :as => :all_evisit_messages
```

Shows up in rake routes like this:

```
all_evisit_messages        /evisits/:token/all_messages(.:format)                                                                   {:controller=>"evisits", :action=>"all_messages"}
```

And I can manually go to it just fine however if I try to redirect to it like so:

```
redirect_to all_evisit_messages_url(@evisit.token)
```

I get a "No routes match - Routing Error" as if the route doesn't exist. I think I defined it correctly... anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
redirect_to all_evisit_messages_url(:token => @evisit.token)
```

Does that work?